# find the record of OutterObject where InnerObject id is x and date is most recent

Tags: java, stream

I am trying to get the id of the OutterObject where the InnerObject id is a specific value and the date is the most recent of all InnerObject of all OutterObject.

I'm trying to achieve that with streams.

Searching for id "ab", it should return "def"
here is a json example of the structre.

```
 {
    "OutterObject": [
        {
            "id": "abc",
            "InnerObject": [
                {
                    "id": "ab",
                    "date": "1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "de",
                    "date": "2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "ab",
                    "date": "3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "def",
            "InnerObject": [
                {
                    "id": "ab",
                    "date": "9"
                },
                {
                    "id": "de",
                    "date": "3"
                },
                {
                    "id": "ab",
                    "date": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How are you representing these as Java classes, not as Json?

Comment: MasterObject containing an arrayList of OutterObject which itself contain an arrayList of InnerObject.

I edited the description and json example.

Comment: You should show those classes, then.  The JSON doesn't really help us answer your question at all.

Comment: The java class is the representation of this json as a java object using arrayList for arrays. It was shorter to just show the data structure as Json. Will update the question later with java representation.

Comment: I found a solution. I'm open to improvement if you see some.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use flatMap to gather all objects in the same array :

   `OutterObject.stream().flatMap(outer -> outer.getInnerObject().stream());`
2. Use max() and Comparator to get the higher value
3. Combine both to get something like :

   `Optional<Date> maxDate = OutterObject.stream().flatMap(outer -> outer.getInnerObject().stream()).max(Comparator.comparing(InnerObject::getDate));`

Comment: This almost work, I think flatmap is the right operator, but it will return an InnerObject and I can't get the id of outterObject. I'm trying variation of that. will add a comment if I find the solution.

Comment: I found a solution. I'm open to improvement if you see some.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved with :

```
        Optional<SimpleImmutableEntry<String, InnerObject>> mostRecentOutterObjectId=  MasterObject.getOutter().stream()
            .flatMap(outter-> outter.getInner().stream()
                    .map(inner-> new SimpleImmutableEntry<String, InnerObject>(outter.getId(), inner)))
            .filter(outterMap-> StringUtils.equals(outterMap.getValue().getId(), "ab")))
            .max((innerA,innerB) -> innerA.getValue().getDate().compareTo(innerB.getValue().getDate()));
```

I am open to improvement if you see some.